# Why AdornerLayers are always the top most layers? Is there a way to change it?

Tags: wpf, adorner, visual-tree, adornerlayer, adornerdecorator

1. Why is that the adorner layer is always rendered as the top most layer in an application (under AdornerDecorator - refer screenshot)?
2. Is there a way to change the layer/level on to which the adorners can be drawn?

In the following screenshot, AdornerLayer is added to AdornerDecorator and the Adorners (MyAdorners) are added to this AdornerLayer. But the AdornerLayer is retrieved like this,

```
        AdornerLayer layer1 = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(button1);
        layer1.Add(new MyAdorner(button1));
```

[image: AdornerLayer - Outline]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my second question,

> Is there a way to change the layer/level on to which the adorners can be drawn?

I guess I have found a solution. Just place an AdornerDecorator element around the level on to which the adorners needs to be rendered. Any control requiring an adorner layer would use this AdornerDecorator element to place its decorators.

Here I have moved the adorners to a different level using the following code snippet.

```
<Window x:Class="CustomAdornerLayer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Background="Yellow" Width="Auto">
        <Button>Button3</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <Grid>
            <AdornerDecorator>
                <Button x:Name="button1" Margin="70,73,265,158">Button1</Button>
            </AdornerDecorator>
            <AdornerDecorator>
                <Button x:Name="button2" Margin="87,51,248,180">Button2</Button>
            </AdornerDecorator>
        </Grid>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</Grid>
```

While the AdornerLayer is still queried in the same way,

```
        AdornerLayer layer1 = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(button1);
        layer1.Add(new MyAdorner(button1));
        AdornerLayer layer2 = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(button2);
        layer2.Add(new MyAdorner(button2));
```

[image: Adorner Layer - Customized]

Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why do you need AdornerDecorator to be the immediate parent of the adorned control?

Comment: Thats my requirement. I want to decorate my button1 with myadorner1 and when button2 is placed on top of button1, myadorner1 should clip and button2 should be visible completely with its own adorner, myadorner2. 

Hope its clear now?

Comment: Not yet to be honest. Does not this happen if they share the same adorner layer? As far as I remember you can set Adorner's Panel.ZIndex attached property

Comment: your solution came after I was banging my head for 2 hours how to implement clipping of the content that I show on the adorner layer. Thank you so much. It's a lifesaver...

Answer (score 3):

Adorner layer is provided by AdornerDecorator. When you ask for the layer for the given control wpf looks for the AdornerDecorator upper visual tree.
Why do you need to change this logic? Adorners system made intentionally this way for decorations to appear above the decorated element.

You can search for AdornerDecorator yourself with VisualTreeHelper

Comment: thanks for you reply. now i understand how the GetAdornerLayer works.