# How to set the Z order index for adorner in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, adorner

I'm trying to set the Z order index for an adorner, currently the adorner is at the top most level and I want to change it to the index of the control it is adorning.

When I call `Panel.GetZIndex(control)` for the control requiring the adorner it returns 0, which I wasn't expecting.

When I attempt to set adorner Z index with 0 or int.MinValue it seems have no affect and the adorner is still at the top most level.

How do you set the Z order index for the adorner?

Answer (score 3):

I think that perhaps you could do with a read of the [Adorners Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN. The reason that you can't change the Z-Index of an `Adorner` is because it is not part of the normal visual tree and in fact, sits in its own `AdornerLayer` that is always on top of the main visual tree. From the linked page:

> Adorners are rendered in an AdornerLayer, which is a rendering surface that is always on top of the adorned element or a collection of adorned elements.

Please note that calling `Panel.GetZIndex(control)` will not do anything for an `Adorner` as it is not in a `Panel`. This is the same as trying to set the `Grid.Row` Attached Property on a `UIElement` that is not in a `Grid`... it will have no effect.

Comment: I'm aware of the architect of adorners in XAML, several other SO questions talk about manipulating the Z order for adorners

Comment: *I'm aware of the architect of adorners*... then you'll know that you can't set the `Z-Index` for them.

Comment: this hints at being able to change the Z order - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209695/why-adornerlayers-are-always-the-top-most-layers-is-there-a-way-to-change-it

Comment: Dude... I'm sorry if you asked the wrong question, but you asked this question and I answered it 'as is'. If you want to implement something specific, then you should have provided that information. I suggest that you either just try the suggestion in your linked question, or ask a new question, clearly stating what you are *actually* trying to achieve... I'm guessing that it can be implemented *without* needing to change the `Z-Index` of the `Adorner` (which is *not* possible).

Comment: no problem, was just trying to resolve a UI edge case, might just remove the adorner all together :)